# How do i expand first div the same width as second div width

Tags: css, html

I have a page with a couple of divs, sort of like this:

```
<div id="content">
  <div id="topDIV" style="background-color: #0000C9; position:absolute; width:100%; top:0px; left:0px; height:44px;">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="height:44px; width:100%;">
      <tr><td>header div<td></tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div id="mainTableDIV" style="background-color: #f00; padding: 10px; position:absolute; top:44px; left:0px;">
   <table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 border=0 style="width:1400px;height:800px">
     <tr><td><td></tr>
   </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

So second div (mainTableDIV) populates via AJAX request and width is set to approx 1400px depends on data.
so when i shrink browser less that this width i see horizontal scrollbar. when i scroll to the right first div (topDIV) which is a header div is not expanding to the same width as second div.
How can i make first header div to be always the same width as second width?

Comment: Now that you shown that it was position:absolute there is a monkey wrench.  Make the container above position:relative,width:1400px then try.  Keep the width:100%.  Have you tried using google chrome (i normally do not support browsers but their HTML debugger is phenomenal.  Right click on the top item and say "inspect element" which will give you a menu to completely debug everything.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap them in a div tag of their own

```
<div id='content'>
    <div id="div_one" style="width:100%;">
        <table width=100%...>
            ...
        </table>   
    </div>
    <div id="div_two" style="width:100%;>
        <div id="data_div"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

First, you do not need width:100% when dealing with a div (as long as there is not a float).  A div will AUTO FILL in the area that its placed in.  So If content 2 exceeds the size of content 1, as long as the overall content container does not have a RESTRICTION on it, in terms of width, the content 1 will grow to meet content 2.

Answer (score 0):

You've got some quotes in strange places, try fixing those and it should work. Besides that, it's a bit clearer if you instead use CSS to set the styles of these divs:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="div_one" class="divider"></div>
<div id="div_two" class="divider"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.class { 
    width: 100%;
}
```

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Hi Michael, I tried your suggestion but it did not work, I posted full example in the original post. I hope it will be more clear. When you shrink browser smaller then 1400 px and scroll to the right first div will not expand. Thanks in advance.